# Multiple instances of TinyMCE: "HTML" button only opens the source of the last instance

Tags: html, tinymce

I have several TinyMCE editors on one page, but when I hit the "HTML" button the popup opens the source of the last editor.

Every textarea has a different ID and when it's called:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "wysiwyg",
    theme : "advanced",
    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",
    relative_urls : false
});
```

It's called four times with the different ids `wysiwyg`, `wysiwyg2`, `wysiwyg3`, `wysiwyg4`.

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you whittle your TinyMCE config down to a minimal test case and post it in your question?

Comment: ``    tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "wysiwyg",
    theme : "advanced",
    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",`

Comment: That will help a lot, but I should have emphasized *minimal* :) If you can make this smaller and still reproduce the issue that would narrow it down and make it easier to test, and in the process you may even find your answer.

Comment: I created a simple page with 4 textareas (ID/Names wysiwyg, wysiwyg2, wysiwyg3, wysiwyg4) and in the SCRIPT tag I called your example TinyMCE instantiation 4 times changing the elements to wysiwyg, wysiwyg2, wysiwyg3, wysiwyg4 respectively. In Safari, Firefox and IE8 with TinyMCE 3.4.7 I found the HTML button correctly loaded the right HTML Source. What version of TinyMCE are you using, what Browser(s) are you seeing this in?